# RabbitMQ Virtual System Failover

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We have RabbitMQ installed on Windows 2012 Server. There are 5 systems in this cluster. During our host patch, the system is migrated from one host to another. During that movement of the system, RabbitMQ will stop running and fail. Causing the need to restart RabbitMQ. 
Have you ever seen this issue? Is there a way to make it so that if the system has to be migrated from one host to another it will be able to handle the minor timeout of the movement of the system?